# R Console - scrolls errors

Tags: r, console

I am working in Mac with a fresh install of the OS. R 3.4.3 GUI 1.70 El Capitan build (7463) is installed on my system.  When I open R Console, I see the following error messages, which scroll continuously until the application is closed.  I have tried installing older versions of R, going back to 3.4.0, but with the same results.  R Studio works without any issues.  Please advise how this may be corrected.

[image: R Console error]

Comment: what's in `~/.Renviron`, `~/.R.profile` and `~/.RData`? (don't post the output, just look there. I suspect something being loaded and I'd start w/deleting `~/.RData` and turning off workspace saving).

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I had already tried deleting .Rprofile and .RData, but had not tried deleting .Renviron.  Still getting the error with these files removed.

Comment: I think the next step is to shoot a message to [r-help mailing list](https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-help) or [r-sig-mac](https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-sig-mac). I say that b/c `changeColor()` is a macOS system-level `ViewController` API method call  designed for applying colors from color choices and could be something that they need to change in `R.app`.

Comment: Having said that, try going to the color picker and deliberately change each color for input/output/prompt/etc and see if that fixes something. it's possible a different preferences file got mangled. Or, delete `~/Library/Preferences/org.R-project.R.plist`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions.  I have tried setting colors for input/output, but it does not solve the issue.  I also took an "org.R-project.R.plist" file from my other machine (same OS and R version) and replaced the file on this machine.  The problem persists.  I have joined the r-help mailing list and will post the question there as well.